# How can I customize the mui-material datagrid header background?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I want to change the design of Mui Datagrid backgriu from
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGYDu.png)
to
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mya3i.png)

But the background color doesn't complete the full header. I tried with "cellClassName:" in the columns but it didn't work.

Any soluction for my problem, i read de documentacion but i can't find how can i resolve

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<DataGrid
  ...
  sx={{ '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders': { backgroundColor: "#99D9EA" }}} 
/>
```

Comment: Thank u so much!